# Ansible construct dict then convert it to string

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this Ansible Template returning me a dict :

```
MY_VARIABLE: "{% set units = ['first', 'second', 'third'] %}\
{% set users_dict = dict() %}\
{% for u in units %}\
{% set u_dict = ({\"dev\": \"app-\" ~ u ~ \"-dev\", \"lead\": \"app-\" ~ u ~ \"-lead\" })%}\
{{ users_dict.update({u: u_dict }) }}\
{% endfor %}\
{{ users_dict | to_json }}"
```

I want `MY_VARIABLE` to be a json string, but when i try and do `{{ MY_VARIABLE is string }}`, the result is `False`.

Can anyone show me how I make it a string without using any intermediary value, like I wanna do everything on the same variable.

Comment: Make it [mre]. Add (at least) the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    units: [first, second, third]
    my_variable: |
      {% for u in units %}
      {{ u }}:
        dev: {{ "app-" ~ u ~ "-dev" }}
        lead: {{ "app-" ~ u ~ "-lead" }}
      {% endfor %}
    users_dict: "{{ my_variable|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: users_dict
```

gives

```yaml
  users_dict:
    first:
      dev: app-first-dev
      lead: app-first-lead
    second:
      dev: app-second-dev
      lead: app-second-lead
    third:
      dev: app-third-dev
      lead: app-third-lead
```

You can convert it to JSON

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: users_dict|to_nice_json
```

```yaml
  users_dict|to_nice_json: |-
    {
        "first": {
            "dev": "app-first-dev",
            "lead": "app-first-lead"
        },
        "second": {
            "dev": "app-second-dev",
            "lead": "app-second-lead"
        },
        "third": {
            "dev": "app-third-dev",
            "lead": "app-third-lead"
        }
    }
```

, or

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: users_dict|to_json
```

```yaml
  users_dict|to_json: '{"first": {"dev": "app-first-dev", "lead": "app-first-lead"}, "second": {"dev": "app-second-dev", "lead": "app-second-lead"}, "third": {"dev": "app-third-dev", "lead": "app-third-lead"}}'
```